# My function for computing a partial derivative generates an error message

Tags: function-construction, warning-messages, core-language

Apologies, I'm still new at Mathematica. I have defined the function

```
ψ[x_, y_] := 
   (C1 Cos[(k y)/Sqrt[Gy]] + C2 Sin[(k y)/Sqrt[Gy]]) 
     (C3 Cosh[(k x)/Sqrt[Gx]] +C4 Sinh[(k x)/Sqrt[Gx]])
```

When I type in `ψ[-a, y]` everything is fine. and I get the output I wanted:

> ```
> (C1 Cos[(k y)/Sqrt[Gy]] + C2 Sin[(k y)/Sqrt[Gy]]) 
>      (C3 Cosh[(a k)/Sqrt[Gx]] - C4 Sinh[(a k)/Sqrt[Gx]])
> ```

But when I type in

```
dx[x_] := D[ψ[x, y], x]
dx[-a]
```

I get the error message

> `General::ivar: -a is not a valid variable.`

but Mathematica still outputs more or less the correct answer

$$
\frac{\partial \left(\left(\text{C3} \cosh \left(\frac{a k}{\sqrt{\text{Gx}}}\right)-\text{C4} \sinh \left(\frac{a k}{\sqrt{\text{Gx}}}\right)\right) \left(\text{C1} \cos \left(\frac{k y}{\sqrt{\text{Gy}}}\right)+\text{C2} \sin \left(\frac{k y}{\sqrt{\text{Gy}}}\right)\right)\right)}{\partial -a}
$$

Is there a problem with when I take the partial derivative of `ψ`?

Comment: Why are you differentiating with respect to `-a` and not `a`? Otherwise, what you seem to intend is to differentiate first before plugging in; in which case, try `ClearAll[dx]; dx[x_] = D[ψ[x, y], x]`

Comment: Oh I see! So in this case `dx` is always the differential of `Psi`, right? I see my mistake now. What I wanted to achieve instead is to make `dx` be the result of the partial differential of `Psi`wrt x and be a function of two variables. Is there a way to do that without having to copy the result of `D[ψ[x, y], x]` into a new cell and assigning it to `dx`?

Comment: If you want partial derivatives, perhaps try `Derivative[1, 0][ψ][-a, y]` for the first partial derivative with respect to `x`, evaluated at `x == -a`. (`Derivative[0, 1][ψ][-a, y]` can be similarly interpreted.)

Comment: These tutorials may be useful for the distinction between immediate `=` and delayed `:=` assignments: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html and https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html

Answer (score 3):

As Roman pointed out, the problem was that I was using `:=` instead of `=`. The following code solved the problem:

```
dx[x_,y_] = D[ψ[x, y], x]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter as to when the value `-a` is substituted for `x` during evaluation. You want the differentiation to be made before the substitution, but the way you wrote the code the substitution is done first. The two normal ways to fix the problem is to write

```
 dx[x_] := Evaluate@D[ψ[x, y], x]
```

or else

```
 dx[x_] = D[ψ[x, y], x];
```

In either case, `d[-a]` will now return

[image: result]